# Python Requests module no longer works

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, certificate, verify

The module used to work but calling it now throws the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Local_PythonScripts\trial.py", line 2, in 
>       import requests
>     File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests__init__.py", line 97, in 
>     
>       from . import utils
>     File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in 
>       from . import certs
>     File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 15, in 
>       from certifi import where
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'

I think I trashed this myself by running some code on PIP in the command console that I copied off Stack Overflow while trying to resolve an error that was saying that a web pages certificate couldn't be verified. The code I ran added something and removed something else and I've tried to find it again so I could show it here but to no avail.

I've tried deleting and reloading "requests" but it won't load the 'certifi' module,  the relevant text I get after running PIP in the command window is:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/:
>   There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): 
>      Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 
>      '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)) - 
>      skipping
>      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi>=2017.4.17 
>      (from requests) (from versions: )
>      No matching distribution found for certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)

Comment: You will have to show us the code you're trying to run in your command console

Comment: I tried running some code that I copied and pasted but have lost.  This is very embarrassing but I can no longer find it.  I'm in a bit of a pickle here.

Comment: The code that got the bottom message was just a simple PIP install:

Comment: i.e. py -3.6 -m pip install requests

Comment: See @Jewel Comment, otherwise if it doesn't work you will have to manually install it

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can install `pip install certifi` then upgrade your pip using this command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` then try to install `pip install requests`. It was worked for me

Comment: Jewel, I still get the same error trying to install "certifi" directly as I do when I try installing "requests".  It says that it cannot find a version of "certifi" that satisfies requirements

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: First of all open your Command Promote as Administrator Access. Then try to execute those command If still not work. so you can setup virtual Environment to execute your python code

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the proposed answer didn't work.  I uninstalled and reinstalled PIP which also didn't work.  Finally, I uninstalled and reinstalled both Python AND PIP and it worked.  I have no idea what I did to it in the first place that could do such damage but that's what it took to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in Pycharm, but when I try to run my py file by cmd, it can work. so I think this happens because Pycharm can't find the directory of certifi.

An easy way to solve this is to install certifi in Pycharm by `Setting-> Projector Interpreter -> +` to search the certifi and install it.